# Angular 4 click event not calling method present in type script file

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I have html form (code given below). i am using angular 4. On clicking button its not calling typescript method present in "admin-form.component.ts" (code given below). Even it is not writing into console. Please help

**Html Code :**
*Filename- admin.html*

```
<form>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fromDate" class="col-sm-2 form-col-label">From Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6"> 
      <input class="form-control" type="date" id="FromDate" name="fromdate"/>
      </div>
     </div>    
    <div class="form-group row">
       <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2" id="Save" type="submit" ng-click="insertSession()">Save</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

**Tyscript Code:**
*File name-admin-form.component.ts*

```
insertSession(){
  console.log('insertSession');
    this.dataService 
    .insertNewSession(this.newSession)
    .subscribe(
      data =>
      {
        this.newSession._id =data._id;
        this.sessions.push(this.newSession);
        this.newSession = SessionDetails.CreateDefault();

        console.log("Added user");

      }
    )
}
```

Comment: you might want to read docs on https://angular.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-click is AngularJs syntax and (click) for Angular syntax.

You need to replace following code :

**(click)="insertSession()"**

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` is AngularJs syntax. you have to use `click` event in Angular 2

```
(click)="insertSession()"
```